# Java Arrays and Inheritance

Tags: java, arrays, inheritance

I always thought that any array type is like a different class but it seems like any reference type arrays are also considered an object of Object[] and their superclasses' array form. (Is this exactly right?)

Consider the following array

```
Integer[] numbers = { 20, 15, 10, 5 };
```

When I pass this array to Arrays.sort which expects an Object[] value, it works fine. But an Object doesn't have any method to compare, how does it know which compare method to use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Integer` implements `Comparable<Integer>` which defines a natural ordering on Integers. Calling `sort` without a `Comparator` relies on the elements of the array to implement `Comparable`, and uses the `compareTo` method of that interface.

Comment: It's waiting Object[] and I'm passing an Integer array. How does it know if i passed an array of integer or student or StringBuilder or any other class? I mean hasn't it lost type information?

Comment: @InsignificantPerson If you read the Java doc of that method, you'll see that `All elements in the array must implement the Comparable interface` and also they `must be mutually comparable`. If you are passing to this method an array containing elements that don't fulfill these requirements, you'll get exceptions. It doesn't care what you pass. It attempts to cast each element that required comparison to `Comparable` and calls the `compareTo` method, passing to it another object.

Comment: thx for the answer but still couldn't get a confirmation about whether every subclass' array type is a subclass of its superclass's array type. For example Cat extends Animal. Does Cat[] extend Animal[] ? (I know it can hold references of Cats but i ask about the array object itself)

Comment: `@InsignificantPerson Since you can assign a `Cat[]` to an `Animal[]` variable, I think you can say that `Cat[]` extends `Animal[]`. For example : `Cat[] ca = new Cat[5]; Animal[] aa = ca;` works.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays.sort is used for **primitive types** and the **Object** as well.

As per the array elements type those are being sorted by using `sort1` but these sort1 methods are private.

1. If you are tying to sort int array. So you will use method `sort(int[] a)`. It will call the private method sort1:

   private static void sort1(int x[], int off, int len) {...}

And this method description is `Sorts the specified sub-array of integers into ascending order.`

2. If you are going to sort Object it will call `mergeSort` method.

**But** When you look at **Integer** class file, it implements `Comparable<Integer>` ([Remember although it's subclass of Object](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html)):

```
public final class Integer extends Number implements Comparable<Integer>
```

So here you don't want to use the Arrays.sort method. By using the `compareTo(Integer anotherInteger)` method the array can be sorted.